# Use direct link instead of postForEntity

Tags: java, spring

I apologize if this question is not constructive, I am new to Spring and can't find the answer (perhaps I search on the wrong context)

I am having a trouble with

```
this.restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class).getBody();
```

It returns null, is it possible to test it manually to make sure the url and the data is correct?

example:
https://sandbox.test.com/checkout_url/

body: {"first_name":"Name",
        "last_name":"Last"}

something like https://sandbox.test.com/checkout_url?first_name=Name&last_name=Last

Comment: Are you also coding the controller?

Comment: @efekctive yes, I also code the controller. But if I am not mistaken, it shouldn't have anything to do with testing the post no?

Comment: Are you hitting the controller? Can you use the debugger, place a breakpoint inside the method in question and step through the code?

Comment: @efekctive yes I tried that, but I still not really understand how the debugger works. but I tried to use postman as suggested by lhhong and I get the correct response, however when I try to print out the result from postForEntity, it return a null. Am I doing something wrong with the method calling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are probably looking at [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). It allows you to make HTTP requests manually.

Comment: Yes, thank you @lhhong ! I get the correct result from that, however I get a null from postForEntity, do you have any idea of why it s happening?

Comment: Sorry, had to comment here instead of above as I do not have enough reputation yet. Could you log your controller and make sure it was hit? You could also check your response.getStatusCodeValue() and make sure it is 2 _ _. Also, I realized you used both request body and request params in your question, make sure you are using the correct one for the request.

Comment: thanks for your input, appreciate it! I figured it out, turns out it is because I did not autowire one of my class and instead use the new() operation, that is why when I debug it, it skips the postForEntity